# How can i edit this registry key so the context menu opens the application as an administrator rather than as a normal user?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, administrator, context-menu

I am currently learning how to edit the context menu via registry key entries, however, i do not know how to open an application as an administrator (in this case a command prompt).

This is the registry i came up with after reading microsoft documentation a little:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Normal Command Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\normalCommand]
@="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\normalCommand\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\normalCommand]
@="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\normalCommand\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


;Admin Command Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AdminCommand]
@="Command Prompt (Admin)"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AdminCommand\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\AdminCommand]
@="Command Prompt (Admin)"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\Background\Shell\AdminCommand\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

In theory it SHOULD work.
However, while it adds 2 command prompt options in the context menu AND one has the shield icon that shows it is running as an administrator, in reality both are non-administrator command prompts.

What exactly am i doing wrong and how do it edit the second part so it opens with administrator privileges?

Searching a little, it seems i need to use `runas` after the shell for it to work, something like this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\AdminCommand\shell\runas\command]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I have seen multiple solutions using powershell but would like to avoid using it until i familiarize with this first.

There are possibly hundreds of solutions for this, but i would prefer to know what am i doing IN WHAT I WROTE rather than copy-pasting a bunch of random syntax hoping for the best.

I tried copying some syntax and while i was able to run an administrator CMD, the entry in the context menu had no icon, even when i specified `"Icon"="cmd.exe"`, so there must be something tricky involved with administrator privileges that breaks other things i wrote.

Comment: If you hold CTRL+SHIFT and then open any application, it always opens as administrator. Alternatively, you can specify for any application, in properties, compatibility, to always open as administrator. But its not possible to start any application as administrator from the commandline that is not admin.

Comment: You have misunderstood everything - `runas` is a command, not registry magic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to edit the Registry to open *any* application as Administrator.

- Create a "desktop" shortcut to the application (e.g., in the User Start Menu).
- Right-click the link and select *Properties*.
- Click *Advanced...*.
- Set *Run as administrator*.
- To add the application to a context menu using the Registry, refer to the location of the *shortcut* (.lnk file), rather than to the application itself.

[image: .lnk properties]

Comment: Desktop shortcuts? What?

I want to add an option to the context menu to open an application with administrator privileges, as specified in the title and post. In this specific case the command prompt.
For this i need to edit the registry to add a new entry to the context menu.

Comment: @Flonne, no, *read the answer*. Use the shortcut in the Registry entry.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not placing these shortcuts on the desktop. Once you add it to the registry, the shortcut location is fixed, and its too easy to accidentally remove such shortcut from the desktop.

Comment: @LPChip good point... all my shortcuts are actually in the Start Menu.